# Magento 2 - Configurable how to get Name of first associated product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, attributes, configurable-product

I need to get the name and assigned attributes value of the first associated product of configurable in Magento 2.

I use something like this:

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

but this return the value of the configurable product not the value of associated product.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//$product = $this->productRepository->getById(725);
$childProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $child */
foreach($childProducts as $child) {
    echo $child->getId();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, the code is work but how I can display only the first product ID? this code display the ID for all associated products, I need to get only the first product ID.

Comment: You need to add break; inside loop;

Comment: indeed, thank you very much, is work like a charm ... I really appreciate your quick help